# What is the registry key for 'Enhanced Pointer Precision' option in the Mouse Properties

Tags: windows, mouse, windows-registry

I use a Razer mouse at work, and though the mouse is supercool, it's driver always removes the 'Enhanced Pointer Precision' option from the Pointer Options tab found in the Mouse Properties of Control Panel on startup. If I could find the correct registry setting to set this option 'on' whenever Windows starts, it would solve my problem. I've tried finding the correct key using [`Process Monitor`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), I didn't get success. Anyone know the key??

Comment: Are you sure it's saved in the registry?

Comment: Good question..I guess it's saved in the Registry. Is there anywhere else Windows stores such config data..I think not!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you were doing wrong in Process Monitor, because I just used it successfully. I found a number of values under the key `HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse`. I also noticed that clicking "Enhance pointer precision" changes the mouse behavior immediately **without writing to the registry** (reg is written when you click Apply or OK), so I would expect that changing the registry values with Regedit would not have any effect until a reboot.

Googling, I found the registry values are documented by MS [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978664.aspx). It refers to Win2000 but the same registry values are used in XP. (the mouse control panel might call the settings by different names though)

Comment: It should be noted that your mouse driver may tweak these and other settings like the acceleration (especially if you use things like “gamer settings”, etc.)